# Should I weedkill soil before sewing a new lawn?

Tags: grass, weed-control

I prepared soil for a new lawn (actually grass covered carpark using soil filled plastic grids) in the winter, about 250m2 in England.

As I prepare to seed it, I notice a little grass and some weeds are already growing. Should I spray weedkiller before laying the seed and if so how long do I need to leave in between?